# Bind ID dynamically on a textbox

Tags: asp.net, eval

I have

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBidAmmount<%#Eval("id") %>" Width="250" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

That wouldn't work and I have read some options that I have to replace the `"` with `'`, so I did:

```
<asp:TextBox ID='txtBidAmmount<%#Eval("id") %>' Width="250" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

But I get:

```
Parser Error Message: 'txtBidAmmount<%#Eval("id") %>' is not a valid identifier.
```

Comment: Where your textbox is located, in aspx page or something like GridView or ..... ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set ID dynamically. That is, if you have `runat="server"` then ID must be a **COMPILE TIME CONSTANT**.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `ClientIDMode="Predictable"` for your repeater/gridview?

[Example from CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-4-0-Client-ID-Feature)

```
<asp:GridView ID="EmployeesNoSuffix" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" ClientIDMode="Predictable">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
         <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="EmployeeID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
         <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="EmployeeName" 
        runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
         </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Output HTML

```
<table id="EmployeesNoSuffix" style="border-collapse: collapse" 
    cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <th scope="col">ID</th>
       <th scope="col">Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><span id="EmployeesNoSuffix_EmployeeID_0">1</span></td>
       <td><span id="EmployeesNoSuffix_EmployeeName_0">EmployeeName1</span></td>
    </tr>
    ...
    <tr>
      <td>
         <span id="EmployeesNoSuffix_EmployeeID_8">9</span>
      </td>
      <td>
         <span id="EmployeesNoSuffix_EmployeeName_8">EmployeeName9</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ID='<%# "txtBidAmmount" + eval("id") %>'
```

**OR**

```
ID='<%# Eval("id", "txtBidAmmount {0}") %>'
```